# IndexOutOfBoundsException on getRef().removeValue in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, indexoutofboundsexception, firebaseui

I'm getting this exception:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
```

When using this code:

```
mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Campaign, CampaignHolder>(Campaign.class, R.layout.recyclerview_template, CampaignHolder.class, ref) {
        @Override
        public void populateViewHolder(final CampaignHolder viewHolder, final Campaign campaign, final int position) {
            final String key = campaign.x;
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("x").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild(key)) {
                        getRef(position).removeValue(new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() { //Crash here
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                                if (databaseError != null)
                                    FirebaseCrash.report(databaseError.toException());
                                else{
                                    if (mAdapter.getItemCount() == 0){
                                        v.findViewById(R.id.empty).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        });

                        return;
                    }
                    //...
            }
```

At this line:

```
  getRef(position).removeValue(new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
```

*(I replaced some strings with `x` because I want to keep em private)*

---

What's causing this issue? How can I fix it?

Comment: The exception gives already a good hint. You are somehow trying to access an element (the one with index 0) in an empty collection (with size 0). What does `getRef(position)` do?

Comment: You should inspect the return value of getRef(position) in the debugger.

Comment: I̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶n̶k̶ ̶I̶ ̶g̶o̶t̶ ̶i̶t̶,̶ ̶I̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶n̶k̶ ̶g̶e̶t̶R̶e̶f̶(̶p̶o̶s̶i̶t̶i̶o̶n̶)̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶r̶e̶t̶u̶r̶n̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶f̶r̶o̶m̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶i̶n̶n̶e̶r̶ ̶c̶l̶a̶s̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶I̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶o̶v̶e̶r̶r̶i̶d̶e̶n̶,̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶f̶r̶o̶m̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶p̶o̶p̶u̶l̶a̶t̶e̶i̶e̶w̶H̶o̶l̶d̶e̶r̶ ̶m̶e̶s̶s̶a̶g̶e̶-̶Nevermind, the inner class doesn't have the method. But this error occurs randomly, why could this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by putting this:

```
DatabaseReference ref = getRef(position);
```

**Outside of the inner class**, and then using `ref` instead of `getRef()`. This solved it for me, at least I think.

Answer (score 0):

The right solution for this problem is here: [Firebase RecylcerView Adapter Not Getting Accurate View Position](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41381399/808901)

> You should not use position outside of populateViewHolder as it value
>   may differ. Instead, make your viewHolder final and use
>   viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() to replace it.

Comment: Which is kind of the same answer as mine

Comment: @AbAppletic Sure, but I think it's more clear show the reason why you should not use position outside of populateViewHolder.